# Does JpaCursorItemReader call only the chunk size or the full data on every chunk operation?

Tags: sql, spring, spring-batch, jpql

**Item Reader code**:

```
    @Bean
    public JpaCursorItemReader<ExtAssessments> extAssessmentsDiabeticReader() {
        String jpqlQuery = "from ExtAssessments WHERE processStatus='new' AND type='diabetic'";
        JpaCursorItemReader<ExtAssessments> itemReader = new JpaCursorItemReader<>();
        itemReader.setQueryString(jpqlQuery);
        itemReader.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        try {
            itemReader.afterPropertiesSet();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.info("Exception in item reader : " + e.getMessage());
        }
        itemReader.setSaveState(true);
        return itemReader;
    }
```

**ItemProcessor code** -> using model mapper to map item to DiabeticAssessment:
**extIdClassMap**: used for single error handling
**updateTargetTableStatusToProcessing**: used to update status to processing and finished

```
    
    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<ExtAssessments, DiabeticAssessment> diabeticAssessmentProcessor() {
        return item -> {
            DiabeticAssessment diabeticAssessment = mapper.map(item, DiabeticAssessment.class);
            log.info("set created by as data migration and created date as current data.");
            diabeticAssessment.setCreatedBy(CREATED_BY_DATA_MIGRATION);
            diabeticAssessment.setCreatedDatetime(Date.from(Instant.now()));
            log.info("update ext Assessment process status as processing");
            updateTargetTableStatusToProcessing(item);
            log.info("Item has been processed for ext assessment id: " + item.getId());
            int hashCode = diabeticAssessment.hashCode();
            extIdClassMap.put(String.valueOf(hashCode), item.getId());
            return diabeticAssessment;
        };
    }
```

**ItemWriter code**:

```
    @Transactional
    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<DiabeticAssessment> diabeticAssessmentWriter() {
        return items -> {
            Boolean isErrorFound;
            String errorMessage;
            for (DiabeticAssessment diabeticAssessment : items) {
                isErrorFound = false;
                errorMessage = "";
                log.info("diabetic assessment data processing: " + diabeticAssessment);
                try {
                    Map<String, Object> validate = isValidate(diabeticAssessment);
                    if ((Boolean) validate.get(IS_VALIDATE)) {
                        diabeticAssessmentRepository.save(diabeticAssessment);

                    } else {
                        isErrorFound = true;
                        errorMessage = validate.get(VALIDATION_ERROR_MESSAGE).toString();
                        //ERROR LOG SAVE METHOD for individual failed
                        log.info("ERROR JOB ID: --->>>  " + jobId + " STEP ID: " + stepId + " Validation error message: "
                                + validate.get(VALIDATION_ERROR_MESSAGE));
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    isErrorFound = true;
                    errorMessage = "Exception during insertion operation";
                    log.info("diabetic assessment data not processed for JOB ID:" + jobId + " And STEP ID: " + stepId);
                }
                if (isErrorFound) {
                    MigrationLogRequest migrationLog = MigrationLogRequest.builder()
                            .extId(extIdClassMap.get(String.valueOf(diabeticAssessment.hashCode())))
                            .jobId(jobId)
                            .stepId(stepId)
                            .fromTable(TABLE_EXT_ASSESSMENTS)
                            .toTable(TABLE_DIABETIC_ASSESSMENT)
                            .message(errorMessage)
                            .severity(DATA_MIGRATION_ERROR)
                            .createdAt(Instant.now())
                            .createdBy(CREATED_BY_DATA_MIGRATION)
                            .build();
                    migrationLogService.CreateMigraitonLog(migrationLog);
                }
                log.info("assessment processing done for uuid: " + diabeticAssessment.getProfileId());
            }
            updateTargetTableStatusToCompleted();
            boolean isSuccessful = validateRecords();
           // if (!isSuccessful) {
                // TO DO
                //ERROR Message for chunk of data process failed
                //   loggerMethod(); //error item
           // } else {
                // loggerMethod(); //success item
          //  }
        };
    }
```

**Step code**:

```
    @Bean
    public Step stepDiabeticAssessmentInfo() {
        return stepBuilder.get("stepDiabeticAssessmentInfo")
                .<ExtAssessments, DiabeticAssessment>chunk(300)
                .reader(extAssessmentsDiabeticReader())
                .processor(diabeticAssessmentProcessor())
                .faultTolerant()
                .skip(Exception.class)
                .skipLimit(300)
                .writer(diabeticAssessmentWriter())
                .build();
    }
```

We can see here **chunk** is 300.

Does the JPQL item reader call only the 300 data items? Or does it call all the data, slowing down the performance every time?

```
 String jpqlQuery = "from ExtAssessments WHERE processStatus='new' AND type='diabetic'";
```

If it calls all data every time, is there any JPQL or item reader approach to fetch the top 300 data where `process_status = new`, then process and save without fetching all data?

Comment: It is a cursor it retrieves what it needs. Make sure you set a proper JDBC fetch size (default is 10) to match (or closer match) the chunk size. jdbc fetch size means how many rows each network roundtrip will deliver (default is thus 10). ANother thing is you are logging, logging is slow, terribly slow. Remove it or at least use it properly (don't do string concat but utilize SLF4J properly). Yet another thing is your mapper, without knowing what is being mapped (as you are using JPA) it might slow things down considerably, why not directly retrieve the DTO you need?

Comment: @M. Deinum I have some complex mapping based on conditions, so I have chosen the Model Mapper Converter function.

Comment: Depending on what your mapper does it will slow down your processing depending on if there are lazy loaded relations/properties involved, collection mapping etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can think of it as a paging query, where the chunk number represents how many items are read on a page,
and then the flow of reading, processing, and writing. Then query the number of chunks defined on the next page.

I hope I understand you correctly and that I can help you